# Проверка работы X-сервера

Tags: java, python, bash, qt5

Периодически зависает X-сервер. Каким образом можно проверить завис он или работает? Проверку необходимо реализовать на python, но и не откажусь от решения на bash, qt или java.

Comment: а может просто посмотреть в лог и исправить проблему?

Comment: если вы сможете определиться с признаками «зависания» с точки зрения операционной системы, то задача будет решена уже процентов на 99.

Comment: X-сервер работает по сетевому проколу, опираясь на модель сокетов. Просто пинганите сокет?